# Android - Qual a diferença entre String e Editable?

Tags: java, android

Ao fazer uso da view EditText, vi que ela retorna um tipo de dado Editable e não uma String. E possui métodos diferentes como `getEditableText()`.

Qual a principal diferença entre String e esse outro tipo de dado [Editable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html)?
Não poderia uma [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) retornar uma simples [String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)?

***Explicações Completas*** são muito apreciadas

Comment: Segundo a documentaçao, a diferença é a mutabilidade, ou seja, a capacidade de alterar o dado. Strings são imutaveis, quando você concatena, é criada uma nova string com o valor antigo e o novo junto, pelo que entendi, esse Editable nao precisa disso.

Comment: Eu realmente não tinha reparado nisso, assim como comentei na resposta do ramaral. Ao editar uma String, é preciso cria uma outra nova. Isso realmente faz sentido. Obrigado Articuno!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

São duas as principais diferenças

- Mutabilidade

  Sempre que aplica uma qualquer operação a uma String é criada uma nova, o mesmo não acontece no Editable onde a operação é aplicada na instância actual.
- Possibilidade de adicionar *markup objects*(objetos de marcação/estilo).

  A um Editable podem ser adicionados *markup objects* para alterar a aparência/estilo do texto, como sublinhado([UnderlineSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan.html)), riscado([StrikethroughSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StrikethroughSpan.html)) e bold([StyleSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html)), entre [outros](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html).

Comment: Faz sentindo. Realmente ao manipular uma String definida é necessário criar uma outra String. Me pergunto se nesse caso, não seria mais conveniente retornar um StringBuilder não? Do que um outro tipo como Editable, embora pela sua explicação, ele seja útil para adicionar estilo ao texto.
De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela resposta! Foi de grande ajuda.